# php mysql_num_rows() function not working

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code to print number of rows in database.Actually there are 3 rows in the database matching to my query.But "echo $num" in my code is not printing anything
Please help.This is my code

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$name=$_POST['name'];
$passwd=$_POST['password'];
$qry="SELECT * FROM user where name='$name' AND password='$passwd'" ;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die("Error attempting query");
$num  = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num;
?>
```

Comment: mixing mysql with mysqli

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`

Comment: try `$num  = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Comment: Also since you are using mysqli, it would be advisable to use prepared statements to prevent the sql injection which currently exists in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mysqli_num_rows($result);` instead of `mysql_num_rows($result);`.